# How to install jQuery into Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add jQuery in my project although i get an error that it is not defined

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/js/svgSprite.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js', mode: 'client' }, <-- gives me error
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vendor/object-fit-images/ofi.min.js', mode: 'client' },
    { src: '~/plugins/js/theme.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
```

Why is this happening, I'm obviously declaring jQuery before bootstrap-select.

Comment: Prefer using NPM, to better handle the versioning of your package. Less error prone too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not recommend adding jQuery to a Nuxt project.

---

But if you **really** want to, you can follow those steps:

- install it with `yarn add jquery`
- add those to your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
import webpack from 'webpack'

export default {
  // ...
  build: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  },
}
```

- be sure that you do have the following in your `.eslintrc.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  env: {
    // ...
    commonjs: true,
    jquery: true
  },
}
```

Then, you can use it like this in a `method` or alike

```js
$("h2").addClass("tasty-class")
```

Comment: Using the plugins property really breaks everything for some reason and creates more problems, i will just stick back to declaring the scripts in the global meta tag which actually makes it work.