# jQuery in Nuxt.js or Setting onClick Event Listener for Anchor Tags

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a Nuxt.js project. In this project, I want to set up an event listener for any anchor tags that happen to be in the body and then do stuff afterward.

The catch is that the anchor tags I want to be listening on are in content that's set up in a CMS, so I cannot bind onClick events in Vue.js the way you normally would. I want to manipulate the DOM to bind onClick events to anchor tags in the body.

In jQuery terms:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery('body').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
                // all my other code that does what I want
            });
        });
    }
};
```

I am trying to setup jQuery in Nuxt.js and I've tried installing it as a plugin (`yarn add jquery` and then adding it to my nuxt.config.js) and I have tried adding the CDN reference to the head. Installing it as a plugin didn't seem to do anything. If I typed `$().jquery` in the console after page load, it returned the jQuery version I have in the head.

However, if I try to add jQuery to the `mounted()` hook on a page, it returns "jQuery is not defined"

An example, which causes the same 'jQuery is not defined' errors:

```
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    // another method that's unrelated; this is not blank in my actual code
  });

  this.jQueryTest();
}
methods : {
  jQueryTest() {
    jQuery('body').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
      console.info('hi');
    });
  }
```

Additionally, I know that generally it's bad practice to mix Vue.js with jQuery. If there's a Nuxt-y/Vue-y way to set up this event listener (an onclick event for any anchor tag that happens to be in the body), then I'd be relieved to hear it.

--

Update: see below for an example of how the project is set up. I've modified details like classes.

```
<div
  class="Card__extras"
>
  <p
    v-show="sectionOpen"
    ref="section"
    class="Card__extras-section"
    :tabindex="isActive ? 1 : -1"
    v-html="sectionText"
  />
</div>
```

sectionText is a string pulled in from the CMS that's something like this:

```
To read more about this story — and other subjects –  check out <a target="_blank" href="https://google.com">This Website</a>
```

Comment: Could you edit with some example of the actual sectionText please?

Comment: @kissu Done! I have added an example of the kind of string I'm working with.

Comment: Damn, what is that CMS? Headless CMS? You should be able to have it shipped with some loaders or some fields that you can get individually. Here, you will be stuck into messy `querySelector`s...

Comment: @kissu It's Contentful, so yes, a headless CMS. I am not sure what you mean about having it shipped with some loaders. I agree that going the querySelector route is messy and it might not be a solution that works at scale either...

Comment: This is pretty much was I am referring too: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/rich-text/

Answer (score 1):

Here is is a guide on how to install jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414170/8816585

Now, should you use jQuery in a Vue/Nuxt app? I'd say definitely not.
If you have 50k lines of legacy code, *maybe*.

Vue/React are declarative, meaning that you just need to tell them what to do, not **how** to achieve this.
jQuery do not have any idea about `state`, nor `reactivity` and is basically a sub-par tool in comparison to modern JS frameworks. On top of being pretty much the same (bundle) size.

I'd say that you are better suited using vanilla ES6+ JavaScript code than jQuery today.

So yeah, as much as possible, use Vue (or Nuxt) and try to not use jQuery. I'm working with Vue for around 3/4 years as of right now, and I never used as of today.

If you need some packages, you can find a lot of cool stuff here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

---

As an example of a simple and quick bind between an HTML element and some JS, you do have this

```html
<template>
  <button @click="test">click me!</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('this is a nice test!!')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

More details can be found on the official [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! The problem was that the jQuery installation steps I was looking at earlier did not include the part where you edit the .eslintrc.js file. jQuery is now working.

Comment: Your code example won't work, by the way. As I said, I am getting rich text from a CMS, and the anchor tags I want to listen on are in that rich text, so I cannot bind click events to anchor tags the way you normally would in Vue.js, hence why I'm turning to jQuery in this instance.

Comment: Could you please show us a bit more what your richtext is looking and what you want to do with it? If it's adding reactivity to some static text, it will be annoying. There's maybe another solution. Also, this is the closest to a `querySelector` in Vue: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements