# How to load script files in Nuxt Js project properly

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am trying to use a HTML/CSS/JS template, which contains JQuery, plugins and some other script files, in a Nuxt JS project. I have included all the script files in **nuxt.config.js** file. Whenever I run the project I get these errors: \

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

This is my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
...
script: [
      {
        src: "/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
      },
      {
        src: "/js/mfn.menu.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/js/animations.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/js/translate3d.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/js/scripts.js",
        body: true,
      },

      {
        src: "/plugins/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.video.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.actions.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.migration.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/plugins/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
      {
        src: "/js/on.load.js",
        body: true,
      },
...
```

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is the answer for the 3rd party scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

And here is how to configure jQuery into a Nuxt project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414170/8816585

Also, give a read to the [plugins documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-plugins#the-plugins-property) to be sure how to use those. And prefer using `npm` packages rather than importing some static `min.js` file.

I'd even say, prefer to avoid jQuery packages as much as possible since Vue gives you all the capabilities of jQuery and even more, having both of them is a waste of JS (impacts performance for the end user).

---

If you still have some issues after those ones (thorough read), feel free to update your question with any additional info!