# place ad code in programme developed with nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am a beginner of programming. Recently I developed a web app with nuxt.js and I would like to insert the following ad code to my programme. However, the ad code structure is different to the one I knew ...

The ad code:

```
<script>(function(s,u,z,p){s.src=u,s.setAttribute('data-zone',z),p.appendChild(s);})(document.createElement('script'),'https://iclickcdn.com/tag.min.js',4760985,document.body||document.documentElement)
</script>
```

Anyone knows how to convert it to the format like :

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      {
        src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
        body: true,
      },
    ],
  }
  // other config goes here
}
```

or you know how to insert it directly to the nuxt.js programme code?

Many thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: This one should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535277/8816585

Comment: Also, this one may be more suited to what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414170/8816585