# jQuery and Vue.js: AutoComplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, vue.js, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a autocomplete field by using jQuery UI to my Vue.js project.

Here is my approach so far. In my template I have:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>
```

In my script I have:

```
   <script>
  import httpVueLoader from 'http-vue-loader'
  import $ from 'jquery'
  import 'jquery-ui';
  
  export default {
    name: 'ResultList',
    components: {
      'ResultItem': httpVueLoader(window.__env.config.HTML_TEMPLATE)
    },
    props: {
      results: Object,
      showAllResults: Boolean,
     },
    watch: {
      results: function () {
        this.refresh_key++
      }
    },
    data: function () {
      return{
        refresh_key:0
      }
    },
    computed: {
      num_results: function(){
        if(this.showAllResults){
            return window.__env.config.NUM_ALL_RESULTS;
        } else {
            return window.__env.config.NUM_PREVIEW_RESULTS;
        }
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {

    
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $(function(){
                console.log("Version would be: " + $().jquery);

                var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
              "BASIC",
              "C",
              "C++",
              "Clojure",
              "COBOL",
              "ColdFusion",
              "Erlang",
              "Fortran",
              "Groovy",
              "Haskell",
              "Java",
              "JavaScript",
              "Lisp",
              "Perl",
              "PHP",
              "Python",
              "Ruby",
              "Scala",
              "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags") . autocomplete ({
              source: availableTags
            });

          });
      });


    
   
    }

    
  }
</script>
```

What went wrong? I am constantly getting the error:

**.autocomplete' is undefined) (2)**
Any help is appreciated!
I wrapped the autocomplete function into a document.ready function but it doesn't help.

When I check separately if the autocomplete function exists it throws that it doesn't.

```
if ($.fn.autocomplete) {
              console.log("autocomplete exists");
          } else {
            console.log("autocomplete not found");
          }
```

Comment: Why do you have a space there? Tried with `$("#tags").autocomplete` (with no extra-space)? Also, why do you use jQuery with Vue? Is it anyhow mandatory in your case, you don't want to do that in Vue?

Comment: Yes, I tried with no extra-space. And yes, I have to use jQuery as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error indicates that the jQuery UI Library has not loaded. Please review your Console and the Source to ensure that jQuery UI Library is loaded properly in the HEAD.

Comment: Yes, the jQuery UI Library was installed via npm and imported. Any other hints for me?

Comment: Did you installed it like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414170/8816585

Comment: Yes! I installed it correctly.

Comment: Why are you importing it in the file here so?

Comment: You can import it globally or in the component file

Comment: No point into importing it locally. If you use jQuery, just go for the global import. Otherwise, don't use it. The middle ground seems to be quite too much engineered.